# Solve integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sin x+ \cos x+\tan x +\cot x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I need to find:

> $$\int\frac{1}{\sin x+ \cos x+\tan x +\cot x}\ dx$$

**My attempts:**

I have tried the conventional substitutions. I have tried the $\tan(x/2)$ substitutions, tried to solve it by quadratic but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What makes you think a closed form solution is possible? Maybe for a definite integral a statement can be made, but I'm guessing if a closed form exists, it will be very labor intensive.

Comment: the integral looks terrible

Comment: The integral is equivalent to $\int\frac{sc}{s^2c+c^2s+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ with $s=\sin(x),c=\cos(x)$, which according to WolframAlpha has a really ugly, complicated solution.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%5Cfrac%7Bsin(x)cos(x)%7D%7Bsin(x)%5E2cos(x)%2Bsin(x)cos(x)%5E2%2B1%7D

Comment: I need to know how to proceed from that step. It may be tedious but if I at least know what to do, then I am satisfied.

Comment: By the tangent half-angle substitution the problem is equivalent to the integration of a ratio between $(1-t)t(1+t)$ and a sixth-degree polynomial in $t$. I.e. just a boring exercise in root finding and partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Jam: it should be correct.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Here's a similar one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497127/integrate-int-frac1-sin-x-cos-x-tan-x-cot-x-csc-x-sec-xdx

Answer (score 5):

Let $t=x-\frac\pi4$ and recognize $2\sin x\cos x= 2\cos^2t-1$
$$I= \int\frac{dx}{\sin x+ \cos x+\tan x +\cot x}
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{\cos^2t-\frac12}{\cos^3t-\frac12\cos t+\frac1{\sqrt2}}dt
$$
Factorize the denominator ($y=\cos t$)
$$y^3-\frac12y+\frac1{\sqrt2}
=(y+a)\left(y-\frac {a-ib}2 \right) \left(y-\frac {a+ib}2 \right)
$$
where $a$ given below is the real root and $b =\frac12\sqrt{\frac3{\sqrt2a}-\frac12}$
$$a=  \bigg(\frac1{2\sqrt2}+\frac16\sqrt{\frac{13}3}\bigg)^{1/3}+ \bigg(\frac1{2\sqrt2}-\frac16\sqrt{\frac{13}3}\bigg)^{1/3}
\overset{\cdot}=1.0758
$$

Then, partially-fractionalize the integrand
\begin{align}
I&= \frac1{3+\sqrt2a}\int \frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}}{\cos t+a}
+\Re \frac{a+\sqrt2 -i \frac{a^2}b}{\cos t +\frac{ib-a}2}\ dt\\
\end{align}
and apply the known integral
$\int \frac{1}{\cos t+p}dt=\frac2{\sqrt{p^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac t2}{\sqrt{\frac{p+1}{p-1}}}
$
to obtain
\begin{align}I
&= \frac1{3+\sqrt2a}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac t2}{\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}} 
+4\Re \frac{a+\sqrt2-i\frac{a^2}b}{\sqrt{(ib-a)^2-4}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac t2}{\sqrt{\frac{ib-a+2}{ib-a-2}}} \bigg)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Solution**

$$\begin{aligned}
&\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)}
\\&=\int\frac{sc}{s^2c+c^2s+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\quad *
\\&=\int sc\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n(s^2c+c^2s)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{(Binomial series)}**
\\&=\int sc\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\left(\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}\binom{n}{k}(s^2c)^{k}(c^2s)^{n-k}\right)\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{(Binomial theorem)}
\\&=\sum_{n\geq0}\,\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-1)^n\binom{n}{k}\int s^{n+k+1}c^{2n-k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}$$

Then the integral in the last expression can be computed iteratively, for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, as:

$$\int s^{a}c^{b}\,\mathrm{d}x
=-\frac{s^{a-1}c^{b+1}}{a+b}+\frac{a-1}{a+b}\int s^{a-2}c^{b}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

This solves the integral as a series but doesn't give a closed form and still has the caveat of infinite terms.

---

* $s=\sin(x),c=\cos(x)$

** The series is the expansion of $\big((s^2c+c^2s)+1\big)^{-1}$, which converges since $|s^2c+c^2s|<1$.

The iterative algorithm for $\int s^ac^b\,\mathrm{d}x$ is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine), on Wikipedia.